# C++ Accessing child methods from parent pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

Ok, I'm from Java and currently trying to figure out this C++ stuff. So I've been doodling around, and I have a basic inheritance going on for a basic RPG game type thing.
Here's on outline of hierarchy:

```
Being (Base object that contains a pointer to a Race)
Race (Base Class)
    -Elf (derived class)
    -Human (derived class)
```

So in my constructor for `Being` I have the following code:

```
        int str,
        intl,
        wis,
        dex,
        HP,
        tHP;
    string name;
    Race *race;
public:
            //Send a reference to an object of a SUBCLASS of Race.
    Being(string name, Race *r) 
            :name(name), race(r){
        str = 10;
        intl = 10;
        wis = 10;
        dex = 10;
        tHP = 15;
        HP = tHP;
        race->applyStats(this);
    }
```

My problem here arises though when I say `race->applyStats(this)`. Although syntactically this succeeds in calling the `applyStats` method of `Race`, I want it to call the one of the subclass. For example, I have a class called `Elf`, that looks like the following:

```
    class Elf : public Race{
public:
    Elf() 
        :Race("Elf"){
    }
    void applyStats(Being *being){
        cout << "entered" <<endl;
        being->setStr( being->getStr() - 2 );
        being->setWis( being->getWis() + 2 );
        being->setTHP( being->getTHP() - 2 );
    }
};
```

And in the main I run this code:

```
Being b ("Tanis", new Elf());
//Don't worry about printStats(), it just lists the stats as the sample output shows
b.printStats();
```

Sample Output:

```
 -Tanis-
 Race Elf
 Strength       10
 Intelligence   10
 Wisdom         10
 Dexterity      10
 Health         15/15
```

Yeah. So I don't really get it, maybe I'm just too used to Java, but when I say `applyStats(this)`, shouldn't it call the `applyStats()` of the `Elf Class`?

Comment: Lookup `virtual` methods.

Comment: Assuming all races have the same stats available, does it need to be a class hierarchy?

Comment: Why would all races have the same stats. That would defeat the purpose of the lesson I'm trying to teach myself... XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In class Race function applyStats must be declared as virtual. For example

```
virtual void applyStats( const Being *being) const;
```

(I changed a little its declaration)

Also do not forget to define the destructor of the base class also as virtual.

You may also define class Race as abstract if you use only objects of derived classes. For example

```
virtual void applyStats( const Being *being) const = 0;
```

Comment: Yeah that works. Thanks a lot :D Will put as answer.